# How to clear the date bound to a CalendarDatePicker if certain conditions occur in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I have a CalendarDatePicker whose Date property is bound to a converter.
I don't want it to show the date if the date is default(01-01-0001)

My code

```
class DateTimeToCalendarDateTimeOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
            return new DateTimeOffset(date);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTimeOffset dto = (DateTimeOffset)value;
            return dto.DateTime;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```

But by default it set's todays date.
What value can I set to clear the date?

Comment: what do you mean by default? you want your CalendarDatePicker to pick a date from the past?

Comment: No initially I want it cleared if my DateTime value is 01-01-0001. And if not it should be set to the respective date

Comment: How did you get the value of your `DateTime`? What you mean by default this value is 01-01-0001? This `DateTime` is your self-defined variable or something?

Comment: Yes it's coming from the server, and it's value happens to be at times 01-01-0001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion we had earlier, I think you wanted to set the the `Date` of the `CalendarDatePicker`  according to the value which is got from a server, but at first this value is set to "0001-01-01" by default.

So you can do it like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:DateTimeToCalendarDateTimeOffsetConverter x:Key="cvt" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="picker" Date="{x:Bind Path=dateTime,Converter={StaticResource cvt}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
private DateTime dateTime;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    dateTime = new DateTime(0001, 01, 01);
}
```

This variable `dateTime` is fake by me and is set in the code behind, and the converter is like this:

```
public class DateTimeToCalendarDateTimeOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var date = (DateTime)value;
        if (date == new DateTime(0001, 01, 01))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return new DateTimeOffset?(date);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var dto = (DateTimeOffset)value;
        return dto.DateTime;
    }
}
```

But be aware that the `Date` is constrained by `MinDate` and `MaxDate`, if `Date` is smaller than `MinDate`, the value is set to `MinDate`. If the `Date` is greater than `MaxDate`, the value is set to `MaxDate`. So if you set the date here for example "0010-01-02", and your `MinDate` is set to "2000-01-01", when return this date in your `Converter`, the `CalendarDatePicker` will show "01/01/2000".

For more information about this control, you can refer to [CalendarDatePicker class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CalendarDatePicker);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)&rd=true).